# Filtering PXselector with search

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom grid using a custom dac that I have declared. Originally i had a PXselector attribute set to POOrder.orderNbr

With this selector it grabs **all POOrders** in my grid selector

```
 [PXDBString(50, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(POOrder.orderNbr))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Po#")]
    public string Po { get; set; }

    public class po : IBqlField { }
```

[image]

But i want the selector to filter POOrders that appear on the **Document details->POReceiptLine**. I attempted to filter using the Search but only get the lowest value POOrder.ordnbr on the receipt. The images below should illustrate what I mean. I want it to show all POOrder.orderNbr but it's only retrieving the first lowest value order.

`[PXDBString(50, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
 [PXSelector(typeof(Search<POOrder.orderNbr,Where<POOrder.orderNbr,Equal<Current2<POReceiptLine.pONbr>>>>))]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Po#")]
public string Po { get; set; }
  public class po : IBqlField { }`

[image: Document Details]

[image: Grid with only lowest order]

Comment: Forgot to add this is on the Purchase order receipt page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it would be much better if you inner join POReceiptLine DAC, and then aggregate associated Purchase Orders to eliminate possible duplicates:

```
[PXSelector(typeof(Search5<POOrder.orderNbr, 
    InnerJoin<POReceiptLine, On<POReceiptLine.pOType, Equal<POOrder.orderType>,
        And<POReceiptLine.pONbr, Equal<POOrder.orderNbr>,
        And<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr, Equal<Current<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>>>>,
    Aggregate<GroupBy<POOrder.orderType,
        GroupBy<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>))]
```

Comment: Thank you Ruslan! I will try all the implementation options that you and Phillipe have given me. I truly appreciate the help.

Comment: I ended up using this implementation, eliminating the duplicates was my intended goal originally as well in the selector. Thank you again both of you guys!

Answer (score 2):

The main issue in the selector is that you are looking for POOrder where the order Number equals the current Receipt Line. That means that depending the line selected, the value will change but will always yield only one result. The solution would then be to change the condition to be on the Purchase Receipt document instead.

To do so you have two options. Either you search directly POReceiptLine.poNbr, but then your selector will display columns from that table, or you join POOrder to POReceiptLine.

1. With search on POReceiptLine

```cs
[PXSelector(typeof(Search<POReceiptLine.pONbr,
    Where<POReceiptLine.receiptType,
        Equal<Optional<POReceipt.receiptType>>,
    And<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr,
        Equal<Optional<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>>>), DirtyRead = true)]
```

2. With search on POOrder

```cs
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<POOrder.orderNbr,
        InnerJoin<POReceiptLine, On<POReceiptLine.pOType,
            Equal<POOrder.orderType>,
        And<POReceiptLine.pONbr,
            Equal<POOrder.orderNbr>>>>,
        Where<POReceiptLine.receiptType,
            Equal<Optional<POReceipt.receiptType>>,
        And<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr,
            Equal<Optional<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>>>))]
```

Also notice the parameter `DirtyRead = true`. This parameter will tell the selector to get it's information in the cache and not only from the Database. Because you are selecting something from the same page, you would need to save the whole document before being able to select the record otherwise. Unfortunatly it would not work with the second option because the Join is done at the database level.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the differences between the two implementations, it's incredibly helpful and i appreciate it.